# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.backend.s1.S1Repo' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, spring-webflux, javabeans

I am getting error like given below i have used annocations like component scan and also I have specfied the annocations properly this is a instance of another big project
I have done the configuration file also i tried the solutions of stackoverflow but still the problem is not solved

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field s1Repo in com.example.backend.s2.S2 required a bean of type 'com.example.backend.s1.S1Repo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.backend.s1.S1Repo' in your configuration.

S1.java

```
package com.example.backend.s1;
import com.example.backend.s2.S2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;


@Service
public class S1 {
    @Autowired
    S2 s2;

    Mono<Integer> testing(int a, int b) {
        return Mono.just(a + 2);
    }

    Mono<Integer> multiply(int a) {
        return s2.multi(a);
    }

    Mono<Boolean> saves1(int a) {
        return s2.saves1(a);
    }
}
```

S2.java is

```
package com.example.backend.s2;

import com.example.backend.s1.S1Repo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class S2 {
    @Autowired
    S1Repo s1Repo;

    public Mono<Integer> multi(int a) {
        return Mono.just(a * 2);
    }
    public Mono<Boolean> saves1(int num) {
        s1Repo.save(num);
        return Mono.just(true);
    }
}
```

S1Repo.java

```
package com.example.backend.s1;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public interface S1Repo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Integer, Integer> {
    Mono<Integer> findById(int num);
}
```

S1UnitTest.java

```
package com.example.backend.service;

import com.example.backend.s1.S1;
import com.example.backend.s2.S2;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import com.example.backend.s1.S1Repo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {S1.class, S2.class, S1Repo.class})
public class S1UnitTest {
    @Test
    void s1test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

the expected is the testcase should run without any errors